# XCode warning : Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast (while trying to assign a value to a NSNumber)

Tags: iphone, xcode, warnings, nsnumber

I'm stuck with a warning in Xcode while trying to develop a small iPhone App.
I've got this piece of code in Xcode :

**NSNumber *randomNumber = arc4random() % [array count];**

If I NSLog randomNumber, everything seems to work but Xcode keeps warning me, saying :

***Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast***

There must be something I didn't understand. Thanks in advance for helping me out :)

Answer (score 6):

NSNumber is an objc object, while an int or float isn't. You're now assigning an int/float to a pointer, which isn't quite right.

Try:

```
// if the result is an int:
NSNumber *randomNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: (arc4random() % [array count])];

// if the result is a float: 
NSNumber *randomNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (arc4random() % [array count])];
```